# Laptop screen turns off automatically while using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: screen, brightness

I am using dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. 
My laptop screen turns off automatically after some time in Ubuntu while the system still remains on. I have checked my brightness and screen settings and there is nothing wrong in that.

It does not happen while using windows but it is irritating to see it happening in Ubuntu.

Please suggest any possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 places you can adjust these setings: the `Brightness and lock` dialog and the `power` dialog.

In the power settings dialog, change the option **"suspend when inactive for"** to  "don't suspend".

[image: power]

In the brightness and lock dialog, change the option **"Turn screen off when inactive for:"** to "never". Also make sure **"Lock"** is OFF

[image: brightness and lock]